# I created an RSA key but SSH keeps asking the password

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys, rsa

On my Mac, I created an RSA key with `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and saved it as `.ssh/authorized_keys` on the target server (Ubuntu).

I put this in server's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
RSAAuthentication yes
```

and restarted SSH. However, it ignores the key. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your key should go to `.ssh/id_rsa` on the Mac, and `id_rsa.pub` from the Mac should be added to the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the server.

You should probably also `chmod -R go-wr ~/.ssh` on the server.

Comment: Yeah, the latter was the case. More details in [my answer](http://serverfault.com/a/360498/55752).

Comment: The command should be: chmod -R go-wr ~/.ssh

Answer (score 4):

[OpenSSH tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) explains how to resolve this problem.

> Chances are, your `/home/<user>` or `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
>   permissions are too open by OpenSSH standards. You can get rid of this
>   problem by issuing the following commands:
>
> ```
> chmod go-w ~/
> chmod 700 ~/.ssh
> chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
> ```

Comment: Finally the answer I needed. Ssh should at least output a warning explaining the key was being ignored by the server of something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You want to connect to your Ubuntu Server without entering a password?

When you generate a new rsa keypair on your mac you end up with a private key (`id_rsa`) and a public key (`id_rsa.pub`). You'll find them in `~/.ssh/` by default.

Login into your ubuntu server and paste the content of `id_rsa.pub` into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.
After this you should be able to connect without a password. On a standard ubuntu system you don't need to touch the `sshd_config` at all.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Turned out, the problem was due to too loose permissions on the `.ssh` folder.